# Is the Orange Peel transparency effect impossible in Eevee?

Tags: transparency

I have a motorcycle windshield with transparency in the alpha channel of the texture. I need the texture to be double-sided and transparent, but apparently Eevee can't handle this.

It seems to me, that if I were to take a sphere, and paint a transparent hole in it, I should be able to make it double sided and be able to look inside of the hole to see the inside.

Hence the "Orange Peel" effect I'm trying to create here. Is this not possible?

Here is the effect I'm trying to achieve. this is a screenshot from Substance Painter:

[image]

The Orange peel effect, where you can see both sides of a single solid object that has a transparency channel. ***Seems to me like any 3D application that supports transparency should be able to do this.***

Here is what I get inside Eevee, with "show backface" checked:

[image]

And here is with "show backface" unchecked:

[image]

So my question is this: are orange peel transparency effects possible in Eevee?

Comment: Could you tell us more details about *orange peel effect*? Since the problem you describe doesn't look like that one defined in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this kind of effect? I don't understand the relationship between orange effect and transparent issue. You might need to confirm what is your main question.

[image: glass in EEVEE]

It should be work while you use **Screen Space Refraction** at *render panel*:

[image: SSR]

You will need to turn on *Refraction* if you want to see thing behind the glass.

And also turn on both **alpha blend mode** and **Screen Space Refraction** in your glass material:

[image: SSR2]

### Reference

[Unable to see objects through Glass BSDF](https://blenderartists.org/t/unable-to-see-objects-through-glass-bsdf/1125009)

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried all those settings, to no avail : ( thanks for taking the time to respond though.

Comment: I feel it may be an issue with using a texture for transparency

Comment: I do encounter some unsolved behavior with glass/transparent when the material node is complex. The strange part was exactly what your question show. But I give up the effect at that time. Maybe you could show how the material is setup in your scene?

Comment: The node system isn't complex at all. I'm crossing a principled shader and a transparency shader, using a third black & white bitmap as the factor (in a mix shader node). That's it.

Comment: If you'd like to look at the node setup personally and see what I'm doing, my Discord handle is TooManyDemons #2125.  I have quite a few years of experience in Blender so I know how things should be working (with a lower margin for error when it comes to experimentation... ) that said, I'm stumped here and could use the help. :P